# smallint vs. int on performance

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

If I know that the value of a column should always be in teh range allowed by the smallint data type, from a data integrity maintenance point of view, it would seem to behoove me to store the data in a smallint column rather than an int column.

However I am wondering whether there are any performance hits that may be paid by using less bytes?

Comment: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/datatypes/ "Always specify the narrowest columns you can. The narrower the column, the less amount of data SQL Server has to store, and the faster SQL Server is able to read and write data. In addition, if any sorts need to be performed on the column, the narrower the column, the faster the sort will be. [2000, 2005, 2008] Updated 2-3-2009"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Smaller types = less storage on disk, which leads to more efficient indexes.  However, those performance gains will be minimal unless dealing with a large volume of data; furthermore, in order to avoid implicit conversions (which may offset any performance gains you see), you'll need to be sure that any time you reference that column that you use the correct type (including comparisons to parameters, etc).

Probably a wash either way.

Answer (score 3):

As Stuart mentions, I expect the performance and storage differences are quite negligible.

It is also worth considering the "domain" you want to model with the given type.  If smallint more accurately models the domain for the data, then its worth making it explicit, even if it doesn't give you a noticeable performance improvement.